# How can I use a select multiple with Jquery Chosen on OctoberCMS (front end)?

Tags: select, twig, jquery-chosen, octobercms

In my old code (CodeIgniter) I use jQuery Chosen to display a select multiple with search. I use this code on the frontend to make it works:

```
<=form_chosen_multiple('location_country',$country_options,1,array('max_selected_options'=>10, 'extra' => 'data-placeholder="Country..." style="width:300px"'));?>
```

Which obviously does not work on OctoberCms front end form.

I searched a lot but can't find any help for now :/

Comment: Are you trying to make a frontend form with select multiple? [Check this out.](https://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_select_multiple.asp) You could make more complex forms by using javascript paired with the OctoberCMS Framework system.

Comment: `form_chosen_multiple` is just helper , you just need HTML to make chosen correct, so check `https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/options.html` here you can find HTML syntax, generate this syntax and it will work